# How do you find the first date of the week in SAS from a date?

Tags: date, sas, intervals

I have a variable in a SAS dataset that has a number of dates (e.g. 01APR21). What I'm looking to do is create a new variable that shows the date of the first Monday of that week. So using the above example of 01APR21, the output would be 29/03/2021 as that what was when the Monday in that week was. I'm assuming it's using intnx, but I can't get my head around it.

```
data test;
format date date8.;
format first_day date10.;
date = '01APR21'd;
first_day = ?;
run;
```

Comment: Does it matter if the first Monday of the week was in the previous month or previous year?   You probably meant to use DATE9. format on both variables. If not then what type date displays do you what to see that require 8 or 10 characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

INTNX Parameters:

- Interval : WEEK
- Increment: 0 (same week)
- Alignment: Beginning
  (Sunday)

Then add 1 to get to Monday instead of Sunday. You could probably play with the [SHIFT INDEX](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm) parameter as well.

```
Monday = intnx('week', dateVariable, 0, 'B') + 1
```

Comment: The above won't work if `dateVariable` is a Sunday, it will return the following day, not 6 days prior. As @Reeza mentions, use the shift index option (in this case, week.2)

Comment: That would depend on how a week is defined by the OP, what you describe happening is what I would expect to happen based on how the question was stated.